# Inequality complex exponential function

Tags: probability, complex-analysis, analysis

How do I Show that for $t \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\mid e^{it} - 1 \mid\leq \mid t \mid
$$
Is it enough to show that $\mid e^{it} \mid = 1$?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2446009/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/584498/42969.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for pointing out. I removed my answer.